# No module named 'statsmodels.tsa.arima' in Colab but not in Pycharm

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, arima

```
# ARIMA example
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
data = [200,30,30,35,30,20,26,35,30,33,40,29,29,30,30,30,30,20,26,35,30,33,40,29,29,30,30,30]
# fit model
model = ARIMA(data, order=(10, 1, 10))
model_fit = model.fit()
# make prediction
yhat = model_fit.predict(len(data), len(data), typ='levels')
print(yhat)
```

The
**from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA** is wokring perfectly in pycharm but while running the same code in colab it throws
[image]
There are very few supports there on internet for this library, so I would appreciate any sort of help or any workaround please.

Comment: It cannot import `statsmodels.tsa.arima.model`, not `matplotlib.pyplot`.

Comment: Sorry I messed up the question. Made it clear now

Comment: No problem with matplotlib.pyplot. Problem is the statsmodels.tsa.arima.model

Comment: Is `statsmodels.tsa.arima.model` your own module or is it a module you installed?

Comment: installed module

Comment: Did you also install it in `IPython`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236739/discussion-between-alan-bagel-and-nagulan-s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try,

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
```

if you don't have statsmodel installed then also do,
pip install statsmodels

Answer (score 1):

You import statsmodels like this:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

And then you can use SARIMA like this:

```
model=sm.tsa.arima.ARIMA(data,order=(10, 1, 10))
```

The arima_model import is deprecated. [You can read more about using ARIMA here.](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need a newer version. Try to run the following in your Colab:

`!pip install statsmodels==0.12.1`

It will allow the import that you want.